# Scaling blocks with overflowing container in slick slider

Tags: containers, slider, overflow, slick.js

I have an issue with scaling blocks in slick slider.
I have a slider with blocks. I want to scale it when hover so used `transform: scale();` property.
My slick sliders shows 5 blocks at a time. When I hover block in it, the block scales but not overflowing slick slider's container.

I found how to fix that by adding to slider container `overflow: visible;` on hover. By default it's `overflow: hidden;`. But then when I hover any of the slider's blocks, hidden blocks of slider become visible on hover as well.

So I would like to ask how to make block scaling in slick slider with overflowing its container but at the same time don't display blocks which are hidden?